# Issue with side by side install vs2008 vs2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have recently installed Visual studio 2013 along side 2008.  I find however that I get an error now when attempting to debug c++ projects.  I assume that vs2013 must have replaced the original debug engine.  Do I need to source the original debug engine, or is there some other known workaround for this?

[image]

If they had just left mixed mode stuff alone it would be ok, but MS makes it real difficult to target dotnet 2.0 with vs2013, plus other things that prevent me from upgrading the solution at this time.

Comment: Very doubtful that this is anything what you think it is.  Much more likely is that you are trying to debug 64-bit code.  Select the property Debug Type in the project's Debugging settings.  Getting stuck on a 9 year version of free software is another problem.  Also rather odd to debug regsvr32.exe, make sure you selected the startup project properly.

Comment: By the way, its not free.  They are both Pro versions.

Comment: Actually, standard 2008, pro 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the answer, for anyone who finds via google.

Somehow, my master solution was set to attempt to debug the dll, rather than the proper exe.  The first option that presents itself when attempting to debug a dll is regsvr32.exe, which was selected at some previous point, but is incorrect.

@Hans Passant, You are correct, it wasn't what I though it was.